# Unbounded *open and connected* set with finite Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I need easy examples of unbounded **open** and **connected** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite Lebesgue measure.

The example that I have in mind belongs to the class of examples which are easy to draw but longer to write down (imagine a countable family of open balls in the plane whose radius decreases as $1/n$, the centers move towards infinity but with a velocity that preserves the overlap so that the connectedness is maintained).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There clearly is no such example if $n=1$.

For $n=2$ a simple example would be $\{(x,y):|y|<1/(x^2+1)\}$. You could give an analogous example for $n>2$.

**Now** it turns out that "I need easy examples of unbounded **open** and **connected** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite Lebesgue measure." is not what the OP actually wanted; he says "It is interesting to me to understand under which conditions on a metric measure spaces a connected open set is bounded if and only if it has finite measure."

Of course it's trivial to concoct a condition  **C** such that **C** implies there is an unbounded connected open set of finite measure. The **C** I have in mind seems unreasonably strong to me, making the proof trivial, but I suspect it nonetheless holds in all the metric measure spaces the OP has in mind:

> > **Triviality.** Suppose $(X,d)$ is an unbounded measure space and $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$ such that for every $x,y\in X$ there exists a path from $x$ to *y* of measure zero. If every ball is connected and every ball has finite measure then then there is an unbounded connected open set.

Regarding my comment on whether that condition is unreasonably strong or not: Imagine a path in the plane. Of course that path can have positive two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. If you're the sort of person who thinks of a path in the plane with positive area as rare or  pathological then the conditions in the triviality seem quite reasonable. Otoh if you're me you think that a "typical" path in the plane has positive measure, so the triviality seems quite weak, having unreasonably strong hypotheses. (Otoh assuming every ball is connected and has finite measure seems perfectly reasonable; certainly not necessary, but the sort of thing you'd expect to have to assume.)

**Note** to be clear, when I say there exists a path from $x$ to  $y$ of measure $0$ I mean there exists a continuous $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ with $\gamma(0)=x$, $\gamma(1)=y$, and $\mu(\gamma([0,1])=0$; in  particular the measure of the path $\gamma$ is $\mu(\gamma([0,1])$.

**Proof.** Say $(x_n)$ is a sequence with $d(x_n,x_0)\to\infty$. Say $\gamma_n$ is a path from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$ of measure zero. Let $K_n=\gamma_n([0,1])$. For $r>0$ let $$V_n(r)=\bigcup_{p\in K_n}B(p,r).$$Now $K_n$ is compact, so $$\bigcap_{r>0}V_n(r)=K_n.$$And $V_n(1)$ is bounded, so $\mu(V_n(1))<\infty$, hence $$\lim_{r\to0}\mu(V_n(r))=\mu(K_n)=0.$$So you can choose $r_n>0$ such that $\mu(V_n(r_n))<1/n^2$, and now $$V=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty V_n(r_n)$$is an unbounded connected open set with finite measure.

**Note** for anyone who detects a whiff of snarkiness here: It's irritating when someone posts a question, and then comments on an answer saying that's not what (s)he wanted! It wastes people's time. If "I need easy examples of unbounded **open** and **connected** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite Lebesgue measure." was really what the OP wanted then the first two sentences of this post would have made him happy - those two sentences give a much "easier"  example of what he *said* he wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about a more general setting where I have just "balls". But your example is perfect! I wait for other proposals as well :D

Comment: @Kosh Make up your mind - you said you wanted an example that was easy to write  down...

Comment: There are many examples that one can create, your example just works in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Lebesgue measure. Maybe someone suggests an example that is not the graph of a function and that can be easily generalized to a more general setting. I don't see what I have to make up; we are in a forum and it is nice to look for other examples coming from different perspectives.

Comment: @Kosh If you want an example in a more general setting you might consider what more general setting you have in mind...

Comment: It is interesting to me to understand under which conditions on a metric measure spaces a connected open set is bounded if and only if it has finite measure. Right now it is not clear to me which is the geometric interplay that assures this phenomenon. It must have to do with how the measure of a ball scales as a function of the radius.

Comment: It's also going to have to  do with how $N_{x,y}(r)$ blows up as $r\to0$, where $N_{x,y}(r)$ is the number of balls off radius $r$ required to connect $x$ and $y$. Seems complicated; I doubt that an interesting/usable necessary and sufficient condition exists. Again, if you had a specific condition in mind I could imagine trying to settle the question for that condition...

Comment: @Kosh Ok, see edit.

Comment: <<It wastes people's time.>> I don't get why someone is wasting time. Anyhow, please calm down, and tell me what's wrong in your opinion about my comment.

PS. I would like to accept one of the answers. Your example uses the whole structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If someone posts an example which highlights the possibility of further consideration in a more general setting, I am going to accept that answer. If in a couple of days no one reply anymore I accept your answer or, equivalently the other one in the same spirit.

Comment: But I read a kind of competition behind this forum that I don't get, maybe because I use mathstack rarely. I think that if one has something non-mathematical to write, he can write it in the comments, not in the answer. Bah.

Comment: @Kosh " Your example uses the whole structure of $\Bbb R^n$". **What?** Have you even glanced at the revised version? You don't see how you're wasting people's time. You say you want $A$, then when someone gives you $A$ you say you want $B$. Then when the same person gives you $B$ _and_ tips you off that he's edited the answer  you don't even _notice_ that he's given you $B$. " I don't get why someone is wasting time." I don't get it either.

Comment: @Kosh You must have glanced at it, since you comment on something at the bottom. _How_ is "Suppose $(X,d)$ is an unbounded measure space and $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$ such that for every $x,y\in X$ there exists a path from $x$ to *y* of measure zero. If every ball is connected and every ball has finite measure then..." using the whole structure of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @Kosh "tell me what's wrong in your opinion about my comment.": Yet more evidence that you're not bothering to read what I write.

Comment: You try to do not understand. I was referring to your first answer. Not to the edited one. You edited the first example just to start a controversy that is the real waste of time you were complaining of. Your answer is not mathematics, I just see a person complaining about nothing, and that moved the focus from math to a controversy. I am not going to read your answer carefully, because I consider most of it off-topic. Maybe you should think to edit it and remove all the off-topic stuff you were writing. After that we can go on discuss about mathematics.

Comment: @Kosh Fascinating. You ask about A. I answer A and you complain that you wanted an answer to B. I answer B, and you say you're not going to read it because I simultaneously complain about the fact that you didn't ask the question you wanted answered. I'd go ahead and make the edit you suggest if I cared - given that you don't care about the question you asked enough to bother to read a simple answer, spending more time on this would be ridiculous..

Answer (score 1):

For $n \ge 2$ take

$$U =\{(x_1, \dots x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_1 >0 \textrm{ and } x_2^2 + \dots x_n^2 < e^{-x_1}\}$$

$U$ is open as it is the intersection of two open subsets. Namely the half open plane $\{(x_1, \dots x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_1>0\}$ and the inverse image of the open subset of the reals $\{x \in \mathbb R \mid x>0\}$ under the continuous map $(x_1, \dots , x_n) \mapsto -(x_2^2 + \dots x_n^2) + e^{-x_1}$.

$U$ is connected as it is path connected.

And $\mu(U)$ is finite.